# ECharts, the maximun data points in surface chart

Tags: javascript, echarts

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G80j4.png)I have a ~70000 x,y,z points, and is from a json file which looks like this:

```
[{"x":134,"y":2,"z":760.8688},{"x":135,"y":2,"z":767.6982},{"x":136,"y":2,"z":770.4304},....]
```

the code as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));
    $.getJSON('ACGC5AB02-2-Thickness.json', function (data) {
        //console.log("data",data);
        var datas = [];
        for (var x = 1; x < data.length; x++) { //
        datas.push([data[x].x, data[x].y, data[x].z]);
        }           
        //console.log("data",datas);

        var option3d = {
            tooltip: {},
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            visualMap: {
                show: false,
                type: 'continuous',
                dimension: 2,
                inRange: {
                    color: ['#313695', '#4575b4', '#74add1', '#abd9e9', '#e0f3f8', '#ffffbf', '#fee090', '#fdae61', '#f46d43', '#d73027', '#a50026']
                }
            },
            grid3D: {
                viewControl: {
                    projection: 'orthographic',
                }
            },
            xAxis3D: {
                type: 'value',
                splitLine: {show: false}

            },
            yAxis3D: {
                type: 'value',
                splitLine: {show: false}
            },
            zAxis3D: {
                type: 'value',
                splitLine: {show: false}
            },
            color: "#383f52",
            series: [{
                type: 'surface',
                        wireframe: {
                        show: false,
                        lineStyle: {
                            color: '#66AEFF'},
                },
                data: datas
            }]
        };
        myChart.setOption(option3d);
    });
</script>
```

I tried to plot a 3d surface by echarts with around 70000 points,
how ever it only plots some but not all..did I missed something?

the out put as below
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/G80j4.png]

Comment: instead of echarts, I switched to use CHAP Links Library  [link](https://almende.github.io/chap-links-library/), and it works fine for me.